# saves the position of an element of a jquery list

Tags: jquery, html, list

I must be able to manipulate a list with jquery.

I created a list with an element already:

```
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

<li id = "1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <p id = "elem1"> Carne </p>
  <button id = "mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>

</li>

</ul>
```

Now, I would like to be able to modify the element, but I would like to be able to save in a general variable the position of the element given to me by the id of the "li" tag.

I wrote this mini function that is activated when the modifier key is pressed.

```
var poscorr;

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#lista1").on('click', 'button', function() {

    poscorr = $("#li").attr("id");

    alert(poscorr);

    });
});
```

But the output of the alert is undefined. Why?
Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `#li` which is a id selector, but in reality you have `<li>` as a element which you are interested to get the `id` value of. Thus you need to use element selector which is `$('li')`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lista1").on('click', 'button', function() {
    poscorr = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
    alert(poscorr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">
  <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem1"> Carne </p>
    <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
  </li>
  <li id="2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem2"> Fish </ p>
      <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="# myModal"> Modifica </ button> 
  </ li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I add a new element, the result is always 1 and not 2 in the second case

<li id = "2" class = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
     <p id = "elem2"> Fish </ p>
     <button id = "mod" class = "badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "# myModal"> Modifica </ button>
   </ li>

Comment: @Benix89 do you need the `id` value in loop?

Comment: Other elements will be added to the list via the function

`code`
var contael = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#elemagg").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
   
     var elemento = $("#elemagg").val();
  $("#lista1").append("<li id = '"+ ++contael +"' class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'> <p id = 'elem"+ contael +"'> " + elemento + " </p> <button id = 'mod' class='badge badge-primary badge-pill' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Modifica</button>");
  
  }
 });
});

`code`

Answer (score 0):

```
poscorr = $("li#1").attr("id");
```

OR

```
poscorr = $("li").eq(0).attr("id");
```

For more details:
https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: `$("li#1").attr("id");` does not make any sense as you already know that the id is `1` by doing `li#1`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save in a variable with a attr,

**Try this:**

```
poscorr=$("#li");
alert(poscorr);
```

**OR**

```
poscorr=$("li").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the position of your **li** tag. For best practice, you need to give a **same class** like *list-hit* for every li tag. Then you should use **click** function of jquery.

```
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

  <li id = "1" class="list-hit list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <p id = "elem1"> Carne </p>
  <button id = "mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data- 
 target="#myModal">Modifica</button>

</li>

</ul>
```

In you jquery then write code for click of jquery event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".list-hit").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('id');
});

});
```